# Remove double qoutes when saving - pear/Config_Lite

Tags: php, file, configuration, pear, ini

Below is my Save Configuration file:

```
<?php

require_once 'Config/Lite.php';

$config = new Config_Lite();
$config->read('/var/www/html/svnmanager/Config/testing');
$config->set('/lol', 'user', 'JohnDoe')
        ->set('/lol', 'password', 'lemo')
        ->set('db2', 'user', '');


// set with ArrayAccess
$config['general'] = array('lang' => 'fr');

echo $config;

$config->save();

?>
```

and following is the output:

```
debug = ""

[db]
user = "JohnDoe"
password = "d0g1tcVs$HgIn1"

[db2]
user = ""
password = "d0g1tcVs$HgIn1"

[general]
lang = "fr"

[/lol]
user = "JohnDoe"
password = "ddada"
```

How do remove the double qoutes when saving the file?
for example:

```
[/lol]
user = JohnDoe
password = ddada
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
$config->setQuoteStrings(false);
```

before saving it to the file

Comment: I did as you said, but it didn't work for me :( `$config->setQuoteStrings(false);
$config->save();`

Comment: That's because you're printing the output before calling this function

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start off with a rant: You are always better off using FLOSS libraries as intended/documented rather than hacking them to do what you want, if at all possible - even when the code is the only documentation available. For example, if a new version of Config_Lite comes out and you upgrade to that, you'll have "lost" your fixes.
(And, as if to prove my point, version 0.2.0 was released today at http://pear.php.net/package/Config_Lite/download/0.2.0)

To be more specific to answering your question, ***you need to call the setQuoteStrings method before you either explicitly save the .ini file output to a file using the write method or do anything that treats $config as a string value***.

Typically, I'd do things in this order:

1. Create the [config] object first.
2. Set whatever options applicable (such as turning off quoted strings in this case)
3. Call whatever other methods as required (e.g. set values to sections etc)
4. Use resultant object (e.g. save the .ini file)

**tl;dr**:

```
$config = ....
$confg->setQuoteStrings(false);
$config->set(...);
echo $config;
$config->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found myself a solution. You need to change the `protected $quoteStrings = true;` to `protected $quoteStrings = false;` in your `Lite.php` file :)